# Is the .copilotignore functionality really working on GitHub Copilot?

Tags: github-copilot

Is the .copilotignore functionality really working on GitHub Copilot?

I added a .copilotignore file on the root of one of my repositories, but Copilot still works on it, ignoring the .copilotignore file.

```
GitHub Copilot v1.105.361Pre-Release
Visual Studio Code 
 Version: I (system setup) 
 Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc3SOaed75ce363ba185c49794 
 Date: 2023 08 (2 aga) 
 Electron: 22.3.18 
 Electronauildld: 22689846 
 Chromium: 108.05359.215 
 Nade.Js: 16.17.1 
 OS: Windows NTxS4 10022621
```

Comment: Appears to be been rolled back: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-20-copilot-content-exclusions-temporary-rollback-and-upcoming-fix/
 Does not work for me either.